# xscreensaver already locked?

Tags: xscreensaver

I'm no longer able to lock my screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>, and

```
$ xscreensaver-command -lock
xscreensaver-command: already locked.
```

What is going on here? Is this functionality broken?

`xscreensaver-command -activate` still works, but that doesn't prompt for the password when dismissing.

```
$ uname -a
Linux hostname 3.0.0-17-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 8 20:45:39 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Congrats on getting it solved, can you add that as an answer? :)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a solution as much as a clobbering of the running processes to get where I wanted. But I'll post it until and unless someone has an explanation of how this could have happened.

Comment: +1 great - dont forget to tick the accept button.  thanks.

Comment: If anybody knows how `gnome-screensaver` could usurp the place of `xscreensaver` I'll accept that answer.

Answer (score 1):

While investigating for a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xscreensaver/+bug/977993), I found that `gnome-screensaver` for some unknown reason was running. The following workaround did the trick:

```
gnome-screensaver-command --exit && xscreensaver &
```

I'd like to emphasize that it's just a workaround, not an answer to why `xscreensaver` died nor how `gnome-screensaver` came to run.